# Delphi XE4 / Firemonkey: Toolbar Look and Feel on OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, uitoolbar, firemonkey

I am currently porting one of my applications to OSX with Delphi XE 4 and the Firemonkey-Framework. Everything works fine, but I am not quite happy with some Firemonkey Look and Feel on OSX (Windows looks fine).

The toolbar looks completely different to the usual native toolbars seen in OSX applications:

[image: Toolbar on Windows and OSX]

As you can see the OSX version toolbar buttons look like simple buttons (which they are). I am using Speedbuttons, which are flat on Windows, but not on OSX.

So my question: Any tips and hints how can improve the looks of the toolbar to make it look more like a native toolbar. Are there better components to use?

thx,
Andy

Comment: FMX, compiles everywhere, native nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows style in Mac, Right click on a control and select "Edit Default Style" and then select "Apply and close" without any editing. Now your app looks like Windows on OSX.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, look much better now.